# Changing the name of Output Function with For loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, export, output

The aim is to change the name of the output file as like variable value changes in FOR loop.

Here is my code---

```
library("igraph")
dd <- read.table("afterFilter(48494).txt")
gg <- graph.data.frame(dd, directed=FALSE)
z=scan("Active_Protein.txt",character(),  sep = "\n")
for(i in 1:877)

    {
    x=adjacent_vertices(gg,z[i])
    capture.output(x, file = "myfile[i].txt") 
    }
```

// Here with the myfile as the value of i changes it shouls save like  myfile1, myfile2, myfile 3 like this.

Please guide me how to reflect the changes in the output file as value changes in i in the FOR loop.

Comment: use `paste0("myfile",i, ".txt")` in `capture.output`

Comment: I already tried with this command. Actually I don't know what is the problem but only capture.out is working for printing result. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: what do you want to do actually? Do you want it on external output or something.

Comment: Z is a vertex here contains 877 vertex name like "YACC67". So aim is to extract the corresponding adjacent vertices from the main graph "afterFilter" and print out the result in the external file.